# How can I use var php with javascript to build custom page?

Tags: pagination, attachments

is variable increment in `$post_per_page = 10`
if click on button next I can increase `$Post_per_page = by_call`
`<button type="button" value="increment++" >Increment </button>`

In `Pos_per_page.php`

```
 $offset = $_GET["offset"]; // gets from primary page
```

the SQL call:

```
"Select blah from blah order by blah limit 50, $offset";


<script>
$(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - 
 $(window).height() - 10) {

$.get('Pos_per_page.php?offset=10', function(data) {
    // only increse
});
   }
});
```

```
 <?php $posts_per_page = 10;
   $attachments = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    /*'numberposts' => 10,*/
   'category_name' => $currentSegment
 ));

 if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $image) {
    $attachmenturl_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($image->ID);
    $attachmenturl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
    $attachmentimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'full');
    $attachmentvideo = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID, 'full');
    $imageDescription = apply_filters('the_description', $image->post_content);
    $imageTitle = apply_filters('the_title', $image->post_title);
?>

    <a data-magnify="gallery" href="<?php echo $attachmentimage[0] ?>" data-src="<?php echo $attachmentimage[0] ?>" data-caption="<?php echo  $attachmentimage[0]; ?>" class="image-grid__item lightbox">
    <img alt='<?php echo $imageTitle; ?>' src='<?php echo $attachmentimage[0] ?> ' class='image-grid__image' /><span class='text-center'> <?php echo $imageTitle; ?></span>
    </a>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it easier to understand? I had to fix the formatting, and it's very difficult to understand the question

Comment: i need increment $posts_per_page by click via jquery. javascript, ajax..

Comment: You mean you want paginated thumbnails? What are you trying to build?

Comment: yes, all attachment have one category, by section render categories and need paginate attachments.